# sql issue for getting highest value distinct wise

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table take for example test in oracle database

`test` has two column 
Column 1 has below value

```
15.1
15.2
15.3
14.1
14.2
13.1
13.5
10.1
10.5
```

and column two has various name value `Kunal , Mangesh.. etc.`

Now through sql query i want to take distinct value of column one and highest value per integer wise means

```
13.5
10.5
15.3 // ect.
```

And its row also means I want highest value of column one number of distinct integer up to decimal value

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand. Anyway, I suppose you wouldn't have got those downvotes, had you said: "I know I get the integer part with TRUNC, and I can get a list of them without duplicates with DISTINCT, but I don't see how to select the highest full number instead", thus showing us you thought about how to solve this and where you got stuck. Maybe by writing this you would have got closer to the solution yourself, as is often the case when properly explaining the issues one is facing :-)

Comment: Are the "decimal values" in `number` data type, or are they `string`? Importantly, can there be `13.12`, and is that less than `13.4` as it would be for numbers, or is it greater, as it would be in a "version and subversion" interpretation of a string? Finally - can there be duplicates in the "decimal" column, and if so, what should be included in the output if two rows are tied for "highest value" for that integer part?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Great point about explaining the problem and our attempts at solving it to others: even if it doesn't always lead to us getting closer to an answer ourselves, it definitely leads to us understanding the **problem** better, which is in itself a great benefit.

Answer (score 2):

To start with: If I understand correctly, the second column with the name doesn't have anything to do with your question.

It seems you want to get the highest number per integer part. So one result row per `TRUNC(col1)` (or `FLOOR(col1)` maybe). Use `GROUP BY` for this. Then you want the maximum value, which is `MAX(col1)` of course.

```
select max(col1)
from mytable
group by trunc(col1)
order by trunc(col1);
```

Comment: my issue is I have one table in database where i have one column with values

Comment: I don't understand. My query contains one table (`mytable`) and one column (`col1`). How is this different from what you are saying?